# AngularJS returing 0 instead of text from the API

Tags: php, angularjs

Recently I tried to fetch some string data from an API using AngularJS. I got almost every string fetch from the API except the following strings. All the below string returing "0" instead of showing the string from the API.

- "m-status":"Approved",
- "s-return-driver":""
- "s-return-day":""
- "dealer-driver":""
- "pd-reason":""

Example : I fetched result from the following Json API.

```
[{"ref_no":"105","ref_date":"2016\/12\/27","log_sheet":"65","branch":"SERVICEB","invoce_no":"8602","invoice_date":"9-11-2016","model_name":"HUAWEI L31","imei":"860906033283604","complaint":"DEAD","c_name":"KHATEEB","c_id":"11111111111","c_phone":"315784","c_cost":"0","battery":"Yes","battery_sno":"0","sim_card":"No","memory_card":"No","remark":"GOOD","esday":"10","branch_transfer":"transfered","branch_carrier":"RASHU","service_status":"Sent for Replacment Rquest","warranty_reason":"FIRMWARE NOT AVAILABLE(URGENT REPLACEMENT FROM OP MANAGER)","complete":"completed","s-return-driver":"","s-return-day":"","dealer-driver":"","pd-reason":"","m-status":"Approved","sbto":"19303","simei":"860906032309319","smodel":"Huawei GT3 4G","sdriver":"Unni","stransfer":"completed","staff_approve":"Approve","staff_drive":"ALI","staff_date":"27\/12\/16","print":"0","final":"0","m-reason":"please proceed","image-link":""}]
```

I fetched result using AngularJS using the following code.

```
{{ x.m-reason }}
```

Please let me know why it showing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's problem of minus sign in variable name you can change `{{ x['m-reason'] }}` it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

> Because your `Json` is an array with a object
>   So you can get the object from the 0th position.

try this way  `{{ x[0].m-reason }}` instead of `{{ x.m-reason }}` .

Comment: I tried it. But still the same result. It showing 0.

Comment: The problem happening only with the following 
    "m-status":"Approved",
    "s-return-driver":""
    "s-return-day":""
    "dealer-driver":""
    "pd-reason":""